# Using ngMock for backend-less testing an external site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

Is there a way to **use angular-mocks.js** to invoke backend-less request mocking, **testing an external site**?  There are plenty of examples using angular mocks on a codebase that the developer has access to add a .  However, I'm stuck in a scenario... calling out to an Angular site, in the wild, which I need to test the frontend functionality, with well-known endpoints/results.

A quick fake example:

1. Call out to `www.externalwebsite.com/RealAngularApp`
2. RealAngularApp calls an endpoint `www.externalwebsite.com/api/v1/getdata` that returns `{ id: 1, name: "testing" }`
3. I need to intercept this (as angular mocks does), but without the ability to add the angular mocks script tag in the code (because it's an external site)

Any/all thoughts are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You've tagged the question with both `unit-testing` and `protractor`. Protractor is used for e2e tests, not unit. In both cases request mocking is done with $httpBackend service, and it is documented well (there's a tremendous amount of questions on this topic also).

Comment: Thank you for your response @estus.  However, this is a bit different than the out of the box implementations that I have seen.  First, I don't have `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somecdn/angular-mocks.js"></script>` available on an external site, nor do I have the (backend) code base to add this script.  Secondly, beyond injecting the script, I have to (after) set up the Mocks for the page requests.  The second part is documented well (as you said), but injecting the script and making sure the binding takes is not.  Thank you again for your thoughts.

Comment: Never had this problem myself, but I guess it should be done like [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2579#issuecomment-145387757) to load angular-mocks.js. And request mocking looks like [this](http://blog.ng-book.com/how-to-mock-http-requests-in-protractor/).

Comment: You asked specifically for `angular-mocks.js` but have you checked https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock? We are using it to intercept Angular http requests and serve predefined responses. No need to modify Angular app code.

Comment: Thank you @finspin!  This was pretty much exactly what I was looking for.  The config part is a bit wonky, but after a short amount of fiddling around, I'm very excited to say the [protractor-http-mock module](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock) you suggested is working like a charm; intercepting the HTTP requests/responses, and without littering the application code with testing implementation.  Please restate this as an answer so others can benefit from this (and I can award you the cred).

Comment: Thank you @estus for the two separate parts on this. I went down this path and was excited when I saw the runBlock populated. However, my excitement was quickly squelched after I found that re-boostap-ing was required before these become available; or as the [Angu‌​lar documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend) states, _**"Afterwards, bootstrap your app with this new module."**_ Nonetheless, I appreciate the direction; it was 90% there.

Comment: It depends on the sequence in which the whole thing runs. If mocking module was added after app module was defined but before it was bootstrapped, the last 10% can likely be done with [`requires`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37244717/3731501), no re-bootstrapping is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock library which lets you intercept HTTP requests and serve predefined responses. Great thing about this library is that you don't have to modify your application code.