# angular 2 inject service into e2e test

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I am writing an **e2e** test for the sign up of users in the app. One of the tests is to check that the user is actually signed up after entering an email and password.

What I would like is, after the test has run, to remove the user that has been created, so the next time the test is run, that user doesn't exist and it can be registered again.

In order to do so, I need to inject my `usersService` into the test, so I can call from the `afterAll` method. Something like this:

```
afterAll(() => {
    usersService.removeUser(userEmail)
});
```

I've seen examples of this for unit tests, but I need it for protractor e2e tests, so I am not sure if that is possible. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: It depends on how the tests are organized. Generally it would be better to not test against real DB, if usersService modifies it. Any way, you can get the service from injector, through DOM `angular.element(document.body).injector()` or like that http://blog.ng-book.com/accessing-angulars-injector-from-within-protractor/ .

Comment: If I wanted not to test against the real DB, is there a way to use a  mocked service from a protractor test? I tried to do that originally what couldn't figure it out. Also, the like you posted, is that also applicable for angular 2?

Comment: Well, it's not a bad thing to test against real DB, it can just be not the same DB that is used in production. If it is freshly created from fixtures in the beginning of the test, there's no problem with persistent state then. It can be done by mocking either sevice or http requests, too. Basically a module with mocks should be loaded to the app. See [comments from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161958/using-ngmock-for-backend-less-testing-an-external-site). It doesn't hurt to do a real request in E2E, this tests CORS at least.

Comment: Regarding A2, it's more or less. Injector can still be saved to `window` to be available in tests. It can likely be available from DOM too, e.g. with `ng.probe`, see https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/debugging-angular2-console/ .

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898015/in-angular-8-how-do-i-access-an-injected-service-from-the-browser-console/57965818#57965818