# In Angular 8, how do I access an injected service from the browser console?

Tags: angular, service, console, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Angular 8.  I'd like to access an injected service from my browser console (Chrome dev tools).  I can access the injector from my browser console like so

```
ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-root')).injector
```

I would like to access an injected service in the dev tools console but when I try this

```
ng.probe($0).injector.get("AbcService")
```

I get the below error.  I have verified the name of my service is correct.  What else do I need to do to access my service from the console?

```
core.js:8991 Uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ActivationService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AbcService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AbcService!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8895)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9140)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9084)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8981)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9140)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9084)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8981)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21208)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21897)
    at Object.resolveDep (core.js:22268)
```

**Edit:** The service I'm trying to access is imported into my component like so

```
import { AbcService } from '@myapp/services';
```

Comment: And service is decorated to be injectable?

Answer (score 11):

The injected service will be available as a property on the **componentInstance**. If AbcService is injected into **AppComponent**

```
  export class AppComponent {  
    constructor(private abcService: AbcService) {}
  }
```

then you can get it in the console with:

```
ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-root')).componentInstance.abcService
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not showing up as a field of "componentInstance".  Do you think it's because its being imported using "import { AbcService } from '@myapp/services';"?

Comment: @Dave how is it being injected into the component?

Answer (score 5):

At least in Angular 10+ the method `ng.probe` does not exist anymore. You can use instead `ng.getComponent`:

```js
// Get the root component
ng.getComponent(document.querySelector('app-root'));

// Any property (injected object) or method in the root component can be used:
const abcService = ng.getComponent(document.querySelector('app-root')).abcService;
abcService.getSomeAwesomeResults();
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was so helpful.  ng.getComponent also exists in Angular 9.

Comment: Some of you might find this helpful for testing if you'd like to update all of the components on a page: 

document.querySelectorAll('app-YOURCOMPONENTS').forEach(component=> { ng.getComponent(component).yourPUBLICFUNCTION()})

Answer (score 2):

injector `get` method token value can be class reference (object) ,string or number value this related how you set the provider

```
providers : [
  AbcService // class ref
]
```

you can get the service like this

```
ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-root')).injector.get(AbcService)
```

> but when you run the app you will not be able to get a refrence to `AbcService` from the developer console ,the `AbcService` is not avilable in global scope.

in case the token is just a string value

```
providers : [
  {provide : 'AbcService' , useClass :AbcService} , 
]
```

this will work

```
ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-root')).injector.get(`AbcService`)
```

> **in both cases if the token does not exist an error will throw**

**Updated**!!

you can save a ref to `NgModuleRef` class like this

```js
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
    window['ngRef'] = ref; // 
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

then can just create an object contains a reference to all service you want to test

```
import {AbcService} from './abc.service';
import {ZService} from './z.service';

export const ServRef = {
  AbcService,
  ZService
}
```

save this object globally

```js
window['servRef'] = ServRef;
```

in the developer console  you can do this

```js
ngRef.get(servRef.AbcService);
ngRef.get(servRef.ZService)
```

[**demo ⚡⚡**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqhtnj)

Comment: When I try typing just the class name ("get(AbcService)"), the console is complaining about not resolving the service name -- "Uncaught ReferenceError: AbcService is not defined"

Comment: It will work if you set the provider for AbcService like this `{provide : 'AbcService' , useClass :AbcService}` where this is not common usually the most common why to set the provider is use the class ref

Comment: As I remember in angularjs the token was string for servises bit in here there is to many options

Comment: Since I'm using Angular 8 (as opposed ot angularjs), do the rules change any?  For example, my providers block has "providers: [AbcService, ...]" but trying "get(AbcService)" and 'get("AbcService")' both fail.

Comment: You cannot  access to the class reference you can save it in global array and use here 

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding you.  Can you add to your answer to explain how I can get a reference to my service with the name "AbcService"?

Comment: Have you tried [ng.probe($0).componentInstance](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20190719-InspectingAngularAppsFromBrowserConsole.html) ?

Comment: I have update the answer and create a demo @Dave hope this will help 